# How to show a mapview callout on view did load

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I'm trying to show a annotation callout right after the mapview loads. I'm sure I'm missing a simple thing but can't find it.

thanks for any help.

here's my code:

my .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapDetailViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate> {

    MKMapView *mapView;

}


// map
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@property (nonatomic) double latDouble;
@property (nonatomic) double lngDouble;

@property (nonatomic) NSString *vendorStr;

@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *costAmount;


@end
```

my .m:

#import "MapDetailViewController.h"

```
@interface MapDetailViewController ()

@end

#define THESPAN 0.01f;

@implementation MapDetailViewController
@synthesize mapView;
@synthesize latDouble, lngDouble;
@synthesize vendorStr, costAmount;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

   // mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    mapView.delegate = self;

    MKCoordinateRegion region;

    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.longitudeDelta = THESPAN;
    span.latitudeDelta = THESPAN;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoord;
    annotationCoord.latitude = latDouble;
    annotationCoord.longitude = lngDouble;


    MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    annotationPoint.coordinate = annotationCoord;
    annotationPoint.title = vendorStr;

    //convert cost amount/ price to string value for the subtitle
    NSString *costAmountStr = [costAmount stringValue];


    annotationPoint.subtitle = costAmountStr;
    [mapView addAnnotation:annotationPoint];


    region.center = annotationCoord;
    region.span = span;

    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];


}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *newAnnotation=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"annotation1"];

    UIButton *disclosureButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [disclosureButton addTarget:self action:@selector(mapCallOutPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    newAnnotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView = disclosureButton;
    newAnnotation.animatesDrop = YES;    
    newAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES;
    newAnnotation.annotation = annotation;
    newAnnotation.draggable = YES;
    newAnnotation.enabled = YES;
    newAnnotation.exclusiveTouch = YES;
    newAnnotation.highlighted = YES;
    newAnnotation.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
    newAnnotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    newAnnotation.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


    //button on the right for popup for pins
        UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rightButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(mapCallOutPressed:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    newAnnotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;


    //Create and add the right button to the callout
    UIButton* rightCalloutButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

    rightCalloutButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [newAnnotation setRightCalloutAccessoryView:rightButton];


    //zoom button on the left of popup for pins
    UIButton* leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
    [leftButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [leftButton addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(zoomToLocation:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    newAnnotation.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftButton;

    UIImageView *profileIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tag.png"]];
    newAnnotation.leftCalloutAccessoryView = profileIconView;


    return newAnnotation;
}


- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views{
    for (id<MKAnnotation> currentAnnotation in mapView.annotations) {
            [mapView selectAnnotation:currentAnnotation animated:YES];

    }
}

// method for the annotation detail disclosure button
-(void)mapCallOutPressed:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"mapcallout pressed");

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should dispatch the `[MKMapView selectAnnotation:animated:]` method with with a slight delay when calling it from `mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views`

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views{
    int64_t delayInSeconds = 0.1;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        for (id<MKAnnotation> currentAnnotation in mapView.annotations) {
            [mapView selectAnnotation:currentAnnotation animated:YES];

        }
    });
}
```

*** EDIT**

Tried on a 6.0.1 device, 6.0 and 5.1 simulator. It definitely works, I suspect you're not setting your annotation title properly by passing  nil.

Try changing the title to a fix value as follows:

```
annotationPoint.title = @"Hello world";
```

*** EDIT2:**

Your property declaration should probably look more like

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *vendorStr;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *costAmount;
```

Comment: thanks, but that didn't work. not sure if it helps, but if I comment out this line   // newAnnotation.draggable = YES; I'm unable to touch the pin which displays the callout.

Comment: I copy pasted your code, tried on the simulator and it was working. Try increasing the delay and check that the annotation.title property is not nil.

Comment: the annotation shows when you touch the pin with the title and subtitle. it doesn't popup on the load though. another strange thing is that if I disable newAnnotation.draggable then you can't touch the pin.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line of code to the `viewWillAppear` method right after you add the annotation:

```
    [mapView selectAnnotation:annotationPoint animated:YES];
```

Comment: That's too bad, it's exactly what I'm doing in my project and it works for me.  Try moving it from viewWillAppear to viewDidAppear.  My code is called after the view is already completely done being displayed

Answer (score 1):

I have waited 0.8 sec after view did appear.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(testMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:.8];

-(void) testMethod
{
    [self.mapView selectAnnotation:annotation animated:NO];
}
```

**animated:NO** did the trick